# WPF MVVM passing textBox data from one View to update a label or a text to another View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In MVVM application developed with WPF with databinding concept, I wouldd like to take a TextBox.Text value from one view to make some changes (Calculation) and displays it in a TextBox located in other view ? Is it possible to communicate directly or I have to pass through a List<> type ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could bind the TextBoxes to the same source property.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to achieve this: for example same DataContext for the views, message system or events.

Comment: Are the views creating their own viewmodels? I think I'm going to make a list of the Top Ten Ways for WPF Programmers to End Up on Stack Overflow Asking Why There's  Bullet Hole in their Foot. Actually I think it's just Top Two. The other's an easy guess.

Comment: yes each view 's related to the its own ViewModel but not directly connected. There's a main ViewModel containnig the others ViewModel

Comment: The problem is when I try to get to the textBox value I have to instanciate and so overload the prevous value

Comment: @vdus Here's the question again: "Are the views creating their own viewmodels?"

Comment: @vdus Please show us the code for "instanciate and so overload the previous value". You have to show us the code. Show us the code. Are you saying that you're trying to do this by creating a new instance of the second viewmodel and setting its properties?

Comment: I don't relay catch it. how can a view can create its ViewModel ? by Instantiating the View class in the .....Xaml.cs file ?

Comment: @vdus I'm going to call that a "no". Are you saying that there is a main viewmodel with two child viewmodels? And one child needs to update a property of the other child?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142185/discussion-between-vdus-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 0):

The problem: We have a main viewmodel with two child viewmodels, and we want the child viewmodels each to reciprocally update some similar property that the other one has. Let's say each has a property named `Value`, and we want to keep `ChildA.Value` in sync with `ChildB.Value`, both ways. For an added wrinkle, we don't want the values the same; we want each to bear some arbitrary relationship with the other. Maybe one is Celsius and the other is hard to spell. That sort of thing.

Thankfully, this is a viewmodel-centric design so the existing code won't be fighting us.

If these are properly designed viewmodels, they'll derive from a common base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and they'll raise `PropertyChanged` when their property values change. I'm calling that base class `ViewModelBase` but it could be anything. I'm also assuming it's written in C#6, so the `OnPropertyChanged()` method (which raises `PropertyChanged`) can be written in such a way as to be called without arguments.

What we'll do is give the main viewmodel sole responsibility for managing the relationship between the children. The children don't know the relationship exists, because lateral dependencies like that usually end in tears. Let each class just worry about its own properties, and those of its children. Thus, `MainViewModel` is the only class responsible for worrying about the relationship between `ChildA` and `ChildB`.

Since `ChildA` and `ChildB` both implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, we can use that to manage the relationship.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ChildA.PropertyChanged += ChildA_PropertyChanged;
        ChildB.PropertyChanged += ChildB_PropertyChanged;
    }

    public static readonly double ConversionFactor = 2000.0 / 4.5;

    private void ChildA_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChildA.Value))
        {
            ChildB.Value = ChildA.Value * ConversionFactor;
        }
    }

    private void ChildB_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChildB.Value))
        {
            ChildA.Value = ChildB.Value / ConversionFactor;
        }
    }

    public ChildAViewModel ChildA { get; } = new ChildAViewModel();
    public ChildBViewModel ChildB { get; } = new ChildBViewModel();
}

public class ChildAViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double _value = 0.0;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            //  This "if" is important: If the value is not changing, we must 
            //  not raise PropertyChanged, because that will put us in an 
            //  infinite recursive loop. 
            if (value != _value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ChildBViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double _value = 0.0;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Alternate Solution

Here's another approach: We could give each child viewmodel class a `ValueChanged` event. This is more initial work than the above, but once that initial work is done, some people find it a bit cleaner and more convenient, and certainly more self-documenting.

Before the C#6 `nameof` operator was added to the language, the above `PropertyChanged` version was subject to the "magic string hazard" of changing property names getting out of sync with string literals referencing the property names. Many shops are still using C#5 in production. Where I work, we've gone to a lot of effort to mitigate that risk; people still mutter in hushed tones about "Ed's Magic String Jihad of 2014".

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ChildA.ValueChanged += (s, e) => ChildB.Value = e.NewValue * ConversionFactor;
        ChildB.ValueChanged += (s, e) => ChildA.Value = e.NewValue / ConversionFactor;
    }

    public static readonly double ConversionFactor = 2000.0 / 4.5;

    public ChildAViewModel ChildA { get; } = new ChildAViewModel();
    public ChildBViewModel ChildB { get; } = new ChildBViewModel();
}

public class ValueChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs {
    public ValueChangedEventArgs(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }

    public T OldValue;
    public T NewValue;
}

public class ChildAViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs<double>> ValueChanged;

    private double _value = 0.0;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            //  This "if" is important: If the value is not changing, we must 
            //  not raise PropertyChanged, because that will put us in an 
            //  infinite recursive loop. 
            if (value != _value)
            {
                var args = new ValueChangedEventArgs<double>(_value, value);
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ChildBViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs<double>> ValueChanged;

    private double _value = 0.0;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _value)
            {
                var args = new ValueChangedEventArgs<double>(_value, value);
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its best possible approach, but typically I use Application.Properties.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44037127/454023) from more details.